# Problems with saving DateTime

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

It's my first question! 
In my project when I'm input date in special page, it is saved to database, but when I edit this information in other page it is not display, and i should input information about date again....

It is view for create and edit information:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DatePol)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DatePol)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DatePol)
    </div>


Controller (part of edit):

 //
        // GET: /Uchet/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(string userName, string nameTitle, int id = 0)
        {
            var NameLst = new List<string>();

            var NameQry = from b in db.Users
                          orderby b.Name
                          select b.Name;
            NameLst.AddRange(NameQry.Distinct());
            ViewBag.userName = new SelectList(NameLst);

            var TitleLst = new List<string>();

            var TitleQry = from r in db.Lib
                           orderby r.Title
                           select r.Title;
            TitleLst.AddRange(TitleQry.Distinct());
            ViewBag.nameTitle = new SelectList(TitleLst);




            Uchet uchet = db.Uchets.Find(id);
            if (uchet == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(uchet);



        }

        //
        // POST: /Uchet/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Uchet uchet)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(uchet).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(uchet);
        }
```

Comment: what is the problem in this code?

Comment: @RahulRJ When I edit information date value not show... I can't see inputed info...

Comment: are You same view for create and edit then are u passing object in your controller

Comment: @Dinesh Yes, same, but information of other types (int, string) saves :D

Comment: Show your controller code

Comment: @Dinesh Name of model

Comment: Ya i can understand but i m asking its your table or class from a model

Comment: @Dinesh Class from a model

Comment: Yes now i can understand Datepol is your variable right where you can assign datepol value here

Comment: @Dinesh If I understand You, I assign DatePol value in create page...

Comment: see you are using 2 action result you create two views for each action results and u can use single class for both view create may i right

Comment: @Dinesh Right! But it does not solve the problem with the date...

Comment: Ya because u need to assign value for datpol variable because this is your next page You not passing the value argument in this action so need to assign it

Comment: @Dinesh Ohhh... And where I must assign it? In controller?

Comment: See My answer and assign like that

Comment: If You get the answer Accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like This

```
 Uchet uchet = db.Uchets.Find(id);
        if (uchet == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        else
        {
             uchet.Datepol = db.tablename.FirstOrDefault(s => s.columnname == id).datetimeFieldName; //Like this you can retrive your date time in that brackets are your conditions
        }
        return View(uchet);
```

Comment: What i cannot understand inputed page means

Comment: Sorry! Date value was inputed in other page of project. And I don't undrestand how can I assign uchet.Datepol to this inputed value...

Comment: ok you getting the date value from Create page then stored in database and than you can show that date in edit page may i right. now what u try to do

Comment: Then what is a problem now

Comment: are you want to show a the date in edit page but no one can edit the date field that why u need (Sorry for telling this are you tamil then just comment in tamil because i m not understand your english Sorry once again )

Comment: No. I want show inputed early date and possible to edit this date!

Comment: Yes its always possible but what date you need show here current date or created date

Comment: value of date, which I inputed in Create page, for sample: 20.03.2014

Comment: are you store that date in your data base at creating time

Comment: Yes! in type DateTime

Comment: Now i can understand friend i updated my answer just see it if any problem comment it bye friend